# Charging or replacing old battery pack without burning house down

Tags: batteries, charger, nimh

A wealthy neighbor passed down the [most *awesome* toy ever](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0015UXJOI) for us to give our son under the Christmas tree, but it's got no charger. And I have no idea if the battery pack inside works. That pack is marked "Rechargeable NiMH Battery Pack...9.6V, AA Size, 1300mAh". I looked around online for replacements and people want **$50** for a replacement power cord, and another $50 for a new battery pack! I have a fair number of electrical equipment in my basement because I have engineered some lead acid battery packs as power sources for portable china balls on film sets for grip work. But I'm *not* an electrical engineer.

The battery pack that's inside is the shape of 8 AA batteries, 2 rows of 4 columns, bound together with the electrical ending coming out the end.

A few questions:

1. Why won't this work?  (It says specifically *not* to charge Spike the Dinosaur in its description, but the electrical info seems like it's right). [https://www.amazon.com/Tenergy-Battery-6-0V-9-6V-Standard-Connector/dp/B003R5N8DQ/ref=pd_lpo_23_t_1/142-7582550-5801503?_encoding=UTF8&pd_rd_i=B003R5N8DQ&pd_rd_r=a8ff1222-a82d-43fe-bc39-afa45f731edb&pd_rd_w=EWxZM&pd_rd_wg=Po5kB&pf_rd_p=7b36d496-f366-4631-94d3-61b87b52511b&pf_rd_r=RJK2HJ4QENCBH8XH3X08&psc=1&refRID=RJK2HJ4QENCBH8XH3X08](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003R5N8DQ)
2. If I could find a different pack/charger of the same shape, that has the same power plug coming out of it, would it matter if I switched to a different power source / battery all together?
3. This looks like it would work: [https://www.amazon.com/Blomiky-Rechargeable-Standard-Connectors-Vehicles/dp/B07MX2LJSD/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?dchild=1&keywords=9.6v+AA+size+NiMH+battery+pack&qid=1608220463&s=toys-and-games&sr=1-1-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUEyS1czNlhPOU9YSkYzJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwMDc0MDk4MjBWWlFOMElHTlBDTCZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMDcwMDQ2M05FN0FSR0w2OVQwMCZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MX2LJSD)

Thanks for any advice!
Wade

Answer (score 0):

> Why won't this work?

It will work, with caveats.

NiMH batteries have more relaxed charging requirements than lithium (which *will* blow up if strict voltage limits are not adhered to), lead-acid (which will be damaged and *may* blow up) or even Nicads, which will eventually be damaged by continuous overcharging.

For 'trickle' charging NiMH the only requirements are that the maximum voltage be sufficient to fully charge the pack, and current is limited to 0.1 'C' ( ie. 1/10th the battery's capacity in Ah). When charged this way it will theoretically take 10 hours to charge, though in practice 12-14 hours is recommended to make sure. In your case that means charging current should not exceed 130 mA. The Tenergy charger has a rated charge current of 400 mA which is 3 times higher than the recommended 'trickle' current for your battery, so it would seem to be unsuitable.

However a NiMH battery can be charged at up to 1C (1.3 A in your case) provided that it doesn't get too hot and current is reduced to ~0.1C once the battery has fully charged. One way to tell that it is approaching full charge is to measure the temperature, and reduce charging current when it goes over ~40 °C.

At 400 mA a 1300 mA battery should take 1300/400 = ~3 hours to fully charge from flat. So this charger should work with your pack provided that you don't leave it on for more than 3 hours, and disconnect it if/when the pack starts getting warm. This charger also has a light to tell you when the battery is charged, and probably reduces current when the light goes on. So just monitor the battery temperature occasionally with your hand, and stop charging if it gets above body temperature or after 3 hours - whichever comes first.

However if the battery is old then it probably will have lost most of its capacity, so don't be too surprised if it seems to reach full charge quickly and has very short run time. Any 8 cell NIMH pack with the same form factor should work fine as a replacement. The Tenergy charger is designed to work with high capacity packs such as the [Tenergy 9.6V Flat NiMH Battery Pack for RC Car, High Capacity 8-Cell 2000mAh.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001BA292A), so if your original pack is no good this would be a suitable replacement.

> If I could find a different pack/charger of the same shape, that has
> the same power plug coming out of it, would it matter if I switched to
> a different power source / battery all together?

Best to stick with NiMH because the device is designed for that. The nearest lithium voltage is 11.1 V, which may be too powerful. Only Lipo (Lithium-polymer) packs come in suitable sizes, and these are extremely dangerous if not handled carefully and charged correctly (they *will* burn your house down!). Lithium batteries will be damaged if over-discharged, and since your toy isn't designed for them it won't shut down before the voltage gets too low.

Comment: Just FYI "At 400 mA a 1300 mA battery should take 1300/400 = ~3 hours" -- not quite.  There are losses during charging (e.g. that temperature increase to 40C is energy lost and it has to come from somewhere).  The "battery university" site https://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/nickel_based_batteries lists NiMH charging efficiency at about 65%, meaning that pumping in e.g. 1 A-h into the battery will charge the battery "up" by 0.65 A-h.

Comment: I'm not sure that's really true. Coulombic efficiency is very high until the battery is almost fully charged http://lygte-info.dk/info/batteryChargingNiMH%20UK.html  - _"This is the last one where I charged 2300mAh into the battery and it could deliver 1917mAh when discharged... A voltage termination will probably stop between 1800 and 1900mAh charged capacity and the discharge capacity will be between 1780mAh and 1840mAh"_ - that's up to 97% coulombic efficiency.